# Sync Folder on Windows Server 2012 with Sharepoint / OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business, onedrive

I want to sync a Folder that is hosted on a Windows Server 2012 R2 and used by clientcomputers on site as a network share to a Sharepoint library (see picture below). The fileshare is not too big, about 500 GB.

Is this possible, and if so, what are the best pointers on how to start?

I've been looking around the internet, but have not been able to find any current (i.e. less than a year old) answers.

[image]

Edit 2020-05-04:

I tried to sync each client to the sharepoint document library using OneDrive.

Here are some of the problems I encountered (not unsolvable, but maybe others find these helpful to know beforehand)

- The five clients started downloading the 500GB simultaneously, which
  clogged the internet connection
- One client ran out of diskspace, as onedrive had no limit, on how much discspace it could use

Comment: Why not do one sync, then have your users use SharePoint instead of the file share?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported scenario and you will likely cause synchronization/lock issues. Sync directly to with your client PCs.